# form_for tag for a resource with two different controllers and RESTful routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for

I have a Rails app with a "Route" resource, and a "Route" controller (not to be confused w/ *Rails* routes).  I've set it up so that the site admins (and only the admins) can manage the "Route" resource through the "Route" controller, while regular users manage their routes with a "Myroute" controller.  I want both controllers to utilize RESTful routing, but I'm having trouble with the form_for function in the "edit" view for the "Myroute" controller.

My form tag for the "edit" view of the "Myroute" controller is currently:

```
<% form_for @route, :url => { :id => @route.id }, :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
```

Which resolves to the following:

```
<form action="/myroutes/44/edit" class="edit_route" id="edit_route_44" method="post">
```

This is not correct, since the form's action should go to the "create" method, and the "edit" method only handles GET requests.  From what I can tell by looking at the HTML generated from the "Route" views, the the form should make a PUT request to "/myroutes/44"

**How do I write a form_for tag so that it uses RESTful routing to make a PUT reqest to the "update" method of a controller that is not the same as the model?**

Comment: Great question! This is really useful when dealing with admin/* routes because the convention of configuration stuff starts to break down there. Hopefully, they'll make this a little more smarter in 3.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
<% form_for @route, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @route.id },
 :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 2):

turns out this also works:

```
  <% form_for @route, :url => myroute_path(@route) do |f| %>
```